# Why I can't start my node/express server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm

Hi I am new to node/express and I am following the express tutorial on mdn (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes).  I added the routes and dummy controller functions and was ready to start the server for testing but I am getting the following error:

```
C:\test-node\libraryapp\express-locallibrary-tutorial>SET DEBUG=express-locallibrary-tutorial:* & npm 
run 
devstart

> express-locallibrary-tutorial@0.0.0 devstart C:\test-node\libraryapp\express-locallibrary-tutorial
> nodemon ./bin/www

[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
C:\test-node\libraryapp\express-locallibrary-tutorial\app.js:16
var mongoDB = mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.d7lji.mongodb.net/local_library?
                         ^
retryWrites=true&w=majority;
                     

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\test-node\libraryapp\express-locallibrary-tutorial\bin\www:7:11)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The above message seems to indicate something wrong with the mongoDB URL but i tripled checked it and it looks correct.  I am not sure what the error referring to bin\www is referring to however.  I had ran the server yesterday successfully after adding the models for the database, but after adding the routes and controllers today I am getting this message.  Thanks

Comment: The url is supposed to be a `string`, check that you didn't forget to put them between quotes

Comment: Thanks @thammada.ts you were right, I missed the quotes.  Still raw with javascript THB but i guess i must have tinkered it without knowing i was missing the quotes after reusing a different DB url today. Thanks again!

Comment: I hope the connection url in the error message is not a valid one, otherwise you'll have to change the credentials, because it is already exposed to the public.

Comment: @thammada.ts thanks I did notice that. I figured its just a tutorial at this point but point well taken.  I think someone already had edited it out for me. Thanks!